# How to animate an ImageView so that once it reaches the upper end of the screen it starts showing from the bottom end of the screen?

Tags: android, xml, animation, translation

Here is what I could achieve:

```
package game.card.translationproblem;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.animation.AnimatorInflater;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView ball;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);


        ball = findViewById(R.id.coloured_ball);
        ball.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(MainActivity.this, R.animator.move_the_ball);
                set.setTarget(ball);
                set.start();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Here is the animation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="translationY"
        android:valueFrom="0dp"
        android:valueTo="-500dp"
        android:duration="5000"/>

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="translationY"
        android:valueFrom="320dp"
        android:valueTo="0dp"
        android:duration="5000"
        android:startOffset="5000"/>
</set>
```

And here is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="700dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/coloured_ball"
            android:layout_width="138dp"
            android:layout_height="141dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ball" />
    </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

I want to perform a translation along the screen so that any portion of the image that goes past the upper edge of the screen immediately shows up from the bottom of the screen.
I thought of using 2 identical images and show one from the bottom at the same time while the other is disappearing from the upper edge but the major objection to this solution is that I can not guarantee the size of the screen and I might just be showing two full images at the same time.

Comment: Is this question clear or ...

Comment: If i had to complete this problem, I would be thinking along the same lines as you, by having two images. Android can be clever to display the images at a constrained size if needed - eg the screen height using a combination of `wrap_content` and `match_parent`, so you are in control of how big you want the images to be. I'd say you want to work out how to find out how far beyond the top of the screen the top image is so you can apply the same inverted translation to the bottom image.

Comment: yeah @Chris I think you understand my problem. I was hoping that there were some quick solution that I didn't know of but there doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 1):

could create the animation via the screen size：

```
void moveBall(){
    // getScreenHeight
    Display display = getDisplay();
    Point outSize = new Point();
    display.getSize(outSize);
    int height = outSize.y;
    //create animator via height
    Animation animator = new TranslateAnimation(0F, 0F, 0F, -(height / 2 + ball.getMeasuredHeight()));
    animator.setDuration(2000);
    animator.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Animation animator = new TranslateAnimation(0F, 0F, +(height / 2 + ball.getMeasuredHeight()), 0F);
            animator.setDuration(2000);
            ball.startAnimation(animator);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    ball.startAnimation(animator);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Anna  for your exertion I just saw you answer.